# Why does Matlab set the background white when saving a scope printed to figure?

Tags: matlab, plot, visualization, matlab-figure, simulink

> I want to programmatically 'Print to figure' a Simulink scope and save the resulting figure to a folder.

Consider following Simulink model and select the scope:

[image]

I run following code (inspired by [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37791364/how-to-programmatically-print-to-figure-in-a-simulink-scope)):

```
scopeName=get_param(gcb,'Name');
hs=findall(0,'Name',scopeName);
hf=figure(1);
hp=findobj(hs.UserData.Parent,'Tag','VisualizationPanel');
copyobj(hp,hf)
filename='test.tiff';
print('-dtiff',filename);
```

Although both the scope and the figure have a black background

[image]

the saved file has a white background

[image]

Is there something wrong with the `print` command or with something else?

Answer (score 2):

By default, MATLAB inverts the background colors when printing to a figure. To get around this, you can set the `InvertHardCopy` to `'off'`

```
set(gcf, 'InvertHardCopy', 'off')
```

Doing this (as opposed to using `getframe`) results in a much higher resolution image as `getframe` simply saves the figure at screen resolution (72dpi).

Another option is to use [`export_fig` from the MATLAB file exchange](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/23629-export-fig) to save the figure which will more reliably reproduce the image that is on your screen.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the same view as you see:

```
img = getframe(gcf);
imwrite(img.cdata,'test.tiff');
```